# Do I need to wear a veil to touch or move the Quran?

Tags: quran, hijab

I am new to Islam and I just received a Quran and was told to put it at the highest point in my room so I am going to put a special shelf up for it. Do I need to wear a veil to touch or move the Quran?

Answer (score 2):

We thank Allah for your acceptance of Islam, and may Allah make our faith and yours remain steadfast.

You do not need to wear a veil to read, touch or move the Qur'an. There is no evidence to that effect. When you come across certain verses in the Qur'an, prostration (*sajda*, Arabic: سجدة) is required. This prostration of recitation (*sujūd al telāwah*), too, does not require that a woman wears a veil (see Islam Q&A: [Is putting on hijab a condition of reading Qu'aan?](https://islamqa.info/en/8950)).

It is also worth noting that elevating the *mus'haf* (the manuscript of the Qur'an) does not mandate putting it on a high shelf; rather, it is about not putting it directly on the floor or in a place where it can be trodden upon or likewise.

The elevation of the *mus'haf* is based on [a hadith in Muwatta Malik](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/515020) where the Prophet ﷺ was talking to the Jews about the punishment of adultery according to the Torah. When a written version of the Torah was brought forth, he ordered that it be put on a chair. Since we as Muslims hold all books revealed by Allah as sacred, and the Qur'an to be the highest among them, scholars deduced that the Qur'an should be elevated from the ground in a similar fashion. Having said that, a higher shelf is better than a chair (albeit not a mandate).